# How to remove Host entry through powershell command

Tags: powershell

I tried to add entry in hostfile as below it worked, need help on removing same entry from hostfile..

Add-Content -Path C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts -Value 20.0.0.1`tlocalhost -Force

Comment: Removing data is harder than adding it. Save the hosts file with different name before adding content. To revert, replace current file with the copy.

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of the original file first, so you can always revert, but this should do it:

```
$path = 'C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts'
(Get-Content -Path $path) | 
    Where-Object { $_ -notmatch '^\s*20\.0\.0\.1\s+localhost'} | 
    Set-Content -Path $path -Force
```

Regex details:

```
^                 Assert position at the beginning of the string
\s                Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
    *              Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
20                Match the characters “20” literally
\.                Match the character “.” literally
0                 Match the character “0” literally
\.                Match the character “.” literally
0                 Match the character “0” literally
\.                Match the character “.” literally
1                 Match the character “1” literally
\s                Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
    +              Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
localhost         Match the characters “localhost” literally
```

Answer (score 0):

Import the content of the File, make changes and export it again...

```
$filecontent = Get-Content -Path C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
$changedfilecontent = $filecontent -replace "20.0.0.1`tlocalhost",""
$changedfilecontent | Out-File "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"
```

(not tested)

Answer (score 0):

I 100% agree with always making a copy of critical files before to do things to it.

```
$HostFile = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts' 
<#
    Directory: C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                         
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        18-Mar-19     21:49            824 hosts
#>

Copy-Item -Path $HostFile.FullName -Destination "$($HostFile.DirectoryName)\$($HostFile.Name)_$(Get-Date -Format 'ddMMyyyy@HHmm')" -WhatIf
<#
What if: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts Destination: C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts_2102202
0@1602".
#>
```

Harder to add vs remove, I am not so much in agreement. 
As it's just a text file, an important one, but just a text file...

1. Read the file as normal
2. select the entire line with target string patten
3. Delete that line
4. Create a new line to add
5. Append the line.

..vs cherry-picking embedded stuff in that line.

```
# Find the line
Get-Content -Path 'C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts' | 
Select-String -Pattern '\d.*localhost.*'
<#
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
#>

# Remove the line
(Get-Content -Path 'C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts' | 
Select-String -Pattern '\d.*localhost.*') -replace ''

# Add a line
Add-Content -Path 'C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts' -Value '  151.101.193.69       stackoverflow.com'

# Or just this
$HostFile = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts' 
Copy-Item -Path $HostFile.FullName -Destination "$($HostFile.DirectoryName)\$($HostFile.Name)_$(Get-Date -Format 'ddMMyyyy@HHmm')" 
(Get-Content -Path 'C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts' | 
Select-String -Pattern '\d.*localhost.*') -replace '', '    151.101.193.69       stackoverflow.com'
```

Oh, and BTW, this has already existed for a while, via the MS powershellgallery.com, so no real need to do this from scratch unless it was a learning effort.

```
Find-Module -Name '*hostfile*' | Format-Table -AutoSize

<#
Version Name                Repository Description                                 
------- ----                ---------- -----------                                 
1.0.2   Web.Helper.HostFile PSGallery  Helper to manage the Windows host file      
1.0.3   Add-HostFileEntry   PSGallery  Adds and removes entries from the HOSTS file
1.0     HostFile            PSGallery  Helper commands to interact with host file 
#>
```

> [Modify Add, Remove - Windows Hosts File Locally and Remotely -
>   PowerShell](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Modify-Add-Remove-Windows-cd052037)
>
> You can Modify Add, Remove - Windows hosts File Locally and Remotely
>   using this PowerShell script. This script has 4 parts #1st part is
>   about adding hosts records, in the local computer or can we deployed
>   via Login script in gpo.# 2nd part is to modify, replace or remove any
>   host entry Download: [modifyhost.ps1](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Modify-Add-Remove-Windows-cd052037/file/157068/1/modifyhost.ps1)

Comment: Thanks all for the inputs, my actual intent was to access https with a fake DNS entry from PS, below worked without adding any entry in hosts .. :).... Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing "https://fakehost" -Headers @{ host="Host"}.         or as below                          https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/4ty9jv/hosts_file_with_a_twist/d5mpxrj/        Invoke-WebRequest http://71.123.236.7 -Headers @{ host = "midnightfreddie.com" }